# Passing a USB device to Qemu KVM

Tags: linux, usb, kvm, qemu, pci-passthrough

I am trying to get my Windows VM to access my USB pen drive, but I am having problems passing this USB over to the VM.

On my Linux host machine, I ran lsusb where my device was identified as

```
Bus 001 Device 018 : ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. Jetflash
```

Looking at a few guides, I tried to pass this USB to kvm using

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 3G --enable-kvm "Windows 10.qcow2" -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=18
```

No matter what I try, I get the error saying "usb-host" is not a valid device.

I tried to change that to usb-storage, since that is the class of device I see for it when doing lsusb -t, but I don't know what to pass for Device ID..If I leave it blank, it says property ".drive" is missing, as expected.

I tried doing a `ls /sys/bus/usb/devices` which printed out some information like

```
1-0:10 1-1 1-1.1 ........usb1 usb2
```

But no matter which id I try and pass along in the command
`qemu-system-x86_64 -m 3G --enable-kvm "Windows 10.qcow2" -usb -device usb-storage,drive=<one of the above>`,

it says no such property with given value exists.

So,

1. Should I be concerned that usb-host is not a valid device?
2. What do I need to do to get `usb-storage` with device id to work?
3. Does qemu-kvm support usb 2, 3 and streaming camera?

I'm using `QEMU emulator version 4.1.0`

Comment: The fact that you're getting a "usb-host" error may mean something. If you do `qemu-system-x86_64  -device help | grep usb-host` does it show up? If not you might need to recompile qemu. usb-storage is probably not what you want, that's for adding a file image as a usb storage device in the VM though maybe it can use a raw device. USB2 is supported. USB3 is not AFAIK but I haven't checked in a long time.

Comment: `usb-host` is *not* among the possible domains names here if I execute a command like the on @CR. gave.

Answer (score 3):

just thought I'd put my two cents in.  I was trying to add a usb printer to my VM and tried the whole "qemu-kvm" command route to no avail.  I eventually just manually added the xml entry into my VM's domain xml following this [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsHostDevSubsys) link.  On the host machine run:

```
lsusb
```

Find the line that represents your usb device.

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:1617 HP, Inc LaserJet 3015
```

"ID" represents your vendor id and product id seperated by a colon.  Then simply replace your devices vendor and product id in the xml code below (include the 0x for hex) and add it as an element with-in your VM's "devices" block:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb'>                                                            
  <source startupPolicy='optional'>                                                              
    <vendor id='0x03f0'/>                                                                        
    <product id='0x1617'/>                                                                       
  </source>                                                                                      
  <boot order='2'/>                                                                              
</hostdev>
```

Good luck and hope this helps.  FYI, to edit your domain's xml file, run:

```
virsh dumpxml yourdomain
```

and then

```
virsh edit yourdomain
```

This will load the xml file you can edit.

Comment: nice! i just removed the   `<address type="usb" bus="2" port="3"/>` from my previous config and press "apply" and the bus and port will be autodetected, when usb device itself is connected. While using virt-manager. Also, I would like to add, the bus=2 and port=3 does not apply on the host machine in either bus or port.

Answer (score 2):

If using a graphical front-end is okay for you,  `virt-manager`'s USB-passthrough works.

In the info section click `add Hardware` and select `USB Host Device`.

I use it to pass pen drives to Windows 10 guests and didn't encounter any problems until now.

If a USB device is added, the machine will not boot, when it is not detected. I.e. the pen drive has to be attached for the VM to boot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this platform, so forgive my formatting.
As indicated before it all starts with

```
lsusb
```

Get the bus and device numbers, in your case 1 and 18.
Then, make a jetflash.xml file containing:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
  <source>
    <address bus='1' device='18'/>
  </source>
</hostdev>
```

You see where the numbers go!
Now, to attach/detach to the running vmID:

```
virsh attach-device vmID /path/to/jetflash.xml
virsh detach-device vmID /path/to/jetflash.xml
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very alike problem, however im using virt manager and i spent hours trying to figure out what could be wrong, initially i assumed something is wrong in my xml file. However I came to the realization that this problem appeared after running `sudo pacman -Syu`

For some reason this made my qemu-hw-usb-host go missing which caused usb host to not be recognized as a valid device name.

My solution was to reinstall libusb
`sudo pacman -S libusb` (not sure if this was necessary) and then `sudo pacman -S qemu-hw-usb-host`

I hope this is a simple and helpful solution for anyone with this problem.