# Issues mapping USB device to VM

Tags: usb, usb-device, lsusb

1. I need to map my USB device (a OnePlus 10T smartphone) connected to a CentOS 7 server to a VM on it. It works fine when I do it in virt-manager GUI, but closing the VM window in the GUI immediately damages a working mapping. Why? If I reopen the VM window I can still see the old mapping there but that doesn't help the VM resume seeing the device - only re-mapping the device again does.
2. Apparently doing the above inserts a hostdev structure into the VM config (virsh dumpxml):

   ```
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x22d9'/>
        <product id='0x2765'/>
        <address bus='2' device='121'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='4'/>
    </hostdev>
   ```

However when (after removing the old mapping made in the GUI) I try using *virsh attach-device* with an xml file with the contents below (assuming 115 is looked up for my device in *lsusb* output beforehand):

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
  <source>
    <address bus='1' device='115'/>
  </source>
</hostdev>
```

the mapping doesn't work (the VM cannot see the device) even though it results in exact same changes in *virsh dumpxml*. I can even see device # increment in *lsusb* output, like it always does when using the GUI way. Am I missing something else here to make it work "manually" w/o the GUI running?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** *virsh attach-device* doesn't work with the following xml file contents as per [this guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-managing_guest_virtual_machines_with_virsh-attaching_and_updating_a_device_with_virsh) either (tried it with *--current*, *--persistent* and w/o them - still no luck):

```
 <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
   <source>
     <vendor id='0x22d9'/>
     <product id='0x2765'/>
   </source>
 </hostdev>
```

Comment: not sure about the `<address bus device>` you use in the XML, but [here is an example of how a USB device is attached to a running VM](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-managing_guest_virtual_machines_with_virsh-attaching_and_updating_a_device_with_virsh) note the use of vendor/product to identify the USb device - also, please show the exact command you run i.e. the arguments you pass to `virsh attach-device`

Comment: @JaromandaX: Thank you: looks like I should be referring to vendor/product indeed. To apply that xml config I used "virsh attach-device MyVM phone.xml" as per StefC's answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561384/passing-a-usb-device-to-qemu-kvm. So I didn't prefix phone.xml with --file.

Comment: @JaromandaX: it also looks like using --current is critical for an immediate effect (that'd then explain why there wasn't any w/o this option) and --permanent helps the mapping survive the USB device and/or the VM or the server reboot, right?

Comment: that seems to be what the documentation for`virsh attach-device` is saying

Comment: Great: I'll report on the outcome once I get a chance to give it a try.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Unfortunately it still doesn't work for some reason. I tried with --current and then with --persistent (they're mutually exclusive) and without them and still no luck either way. Repeated each test twice to be sure.